# How can I change the headings of hash table columns in powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, hashtable, powershell-2.0

I am fairly new to Powershell scripting. I am writing a power-shell script in which I declared a hash table like the following:

```
$a = 1
$b = 2


$my_hash = @{}
$my_hash.Add($a, $b)
```

When I print the table in Powershell, the headings of the hash table shows

```
 Name  Value
 ----  -----
 1     2
```

How can I change the name of each column from "Name, Value" to something like "Application1, Application2"? 
I.e.

```
 App1  App2
 ----  -----
 1     2
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pipe the hashtable to a `Select` command, and build your output on the fly such as:

```
$My_Hash.keys | Select @{l='App1';e={$_}},@{l='App2';e={$My_Hash.$_}}
```

Comment: What's `l` and `e` doing here?

Comment: They are short hand for `Label` and `Expression`. The label gives the name of the property being created, while the expression is a scriptblock used to calculate the value of the property.

Comment: That works fine, but it seems like the following Write-Host statement (in the code) is appearing before the display of my HashTable in the console output. Is it starting a parallel process?

Comment: Added new question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71708221/order-of-write-host-statements-seems-wrong-on-console-output-of-powershell  It happens with the other solution on this page as well.

Answer (score 4):

Building on [TheMadTechnician's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980957/712649), you can make a generic function to rename the "columns":

```
function Format-Hashtable {
    param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
      [hashtable]$Hashtable,

      [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
      [string]$KeyHeader = 'Name',

      [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
      [string]$ValueHeader = 'Value'
    )

    $Hashtable.GetEnumerator() |Select-Object @{Label=$KeyHeader;Expression={$_.Key}},@{Label=$ValueHeader;Expression={$_.Value}}

}
```

Then call it like:

```
PS C:\> $my_hash |Format-Hashtable -KeyHeader App1 -ValueHeader App2

App1 App2
---- ----
   1    2
```