# Order of Write-Host statements seems wrong on console output

Tags: powershell-4.0

In the code below, why does "The End" show up in the console before the list of items in my hash table? If I just use Format-Table the order of the console is normal, but when piping to Select the order seems wrong.

```
cls
Write-Host "Start"
$my_hash = @{}
$my_hash.Add("sent", 5)
$my_hash.Add("failed", 2)
#$my_hash | Format-Table 
$my_hash.keys | Select @{Label='StatusCode';Expression={$_}},@{l='Count';e={$my_hash.$_}}
Write-Host "The end"
```

Output:

```
Start

The end
StatusCode Count
---------- -----
sent           5
failed         2
```

Code is based on a solution for assigning headings to the hash table output here: [How can I change the headings of hash table columns in powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980702/how-can-i-change-the-headings-of-hash-table-columns-in-powershell-script)

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try this way:

```
Clear-Host
"Start"

  $fmtHash = 
    @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="StatusCode";Width=10},
    @{Expression={$_.Value};Label="Count";Width=5}

$my_hash = [hashtable] @{}
$my_hash.Add("sent", 5)
$my_hash.Add("failed", 2)

$my_hash | Format-Table $fmtHash

"The end"
```

Sample output:

```
Start

StatusCode Count
---------- -----
sent           5
failed         2


The end
```

I've eliminated the redundant Write-Hosts and explicitly cast the HashTable then used the Format-Table as a clearer coding method IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, but what was making it behave that way?

Comment: Neal, I'm sure it has to do with passing a Hash Table to Select but I'm not exactly sure what the issue is that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can add piped Out-Host like that, to diplay $my_hash content forcely by script running order:

```
cls
Write-Host "Start"
$my_hash = @{}
$my_hash.Add("sent", 5)
$my_hash.Add("failed", 2)
$my_hash.keys | Select @{Label='StatusCode';Expression={$_}},@{l='Count';e={$my_hash.$_}} | Out-Host
Write-Host "The end"
```

Output:

```
Start

StatusCode Count
---------- -----
sent           5
failed         2


The end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Should be marked as the answer. `Out-Host` makes it work.
... but I would like to understand why...