# How can I read the name of the JSON array in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

This is my JSON file which contains IIS Features and its components.
I want to read this file using PowerShell Script so that each item of the array are listed under their headers.

```
enter code here
```

For example:
**CommonHttpFeatures** (header)
IIS-CommonHttpFeatures
IIS-DefaultDocument 
IIS-HttpErrors 
...

**HealthandDiagnostics**
IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics 
IIS-CustomLogging 
IIS-HttpLogging

...

and so on. Here is PowerShell code below

```
 Clear-Host 
*>>Read in the configuration from JSON file* 
$Config = Get-Content -path 'C:\Scripts\Reading JSON\InstallationConfig.json' | ConvertFrom-JSon

$ApplicationDevelopment = $Config.WindowsFeatures.IISFeatures

foreach($appDev in $ApplicationDevelopment)
{
    Write-Host $appDev
}

$test = @($Config.WindowsFeatures.IISFeatures) 
$test
```

```
"WindowsFeatures":
{
    "IISFeatures":
    {
        "CommonHttpFeatures":
        [
            "IIS-CommonHttpFeatures", 
            "IIS-DefaultDocument", 
            "IIS-HttpErrors", 
            "IIS-HttpRedirect", 
            "IIS-StaticContent", 
            "IIS-DirectoryBrowsing", 
            "IIS-WebDAV"
        ],
        
        "HealthandDiagnostics":
        [
            "IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics", 
            "IIS-CustomLogging", 
            "IIS-HttpLogging", 
            "IIS-ODBCLogging", 
            "IIS-LoggingLibraries", 
            "IIS-RequestMonitor", 
            "IIS-HttpTracing"
        ],
        
        
        "Performace":
        [
            "IIS-HttpCompressionStatic", 
            "IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic"
        ],
        
        
        "Security":
        [
            "IIS-BasicAuthentication", 
            "IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication", 
            "IIS-DigestAuthentication", 
            "IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication", 
            "IIS-IPSecurity", 
            "IIS-RequestFiltering", 
            "IIS-URLAuthorization", 
            "IIS-WindowsAuthentication", 
            "IIS-CertProvider"
        ],
        
        "ApplicationDevelopment":
        [
            "NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45", 
            "IIS-WebServerRole", 
            "IIS-ApplicationDevelopment", 
            "IIS-NetFxExtensibility", 
            "IIS-NetFxExtensibility45", 
            "IIS-ApplicationInit", 
            "IIS-CGI", 
            "IIS-ISAPIExtensions", 
            "IIS-ISAPIFilter", 
            "IIS-ServerSideIncludes", 
            "IIS-WebSockets", 
            "IIS-ASPNET", 
            "IIS-ASPNET45", 
            "IIS-ManagementConsole", 
            "IIS-ASP"
        ]
        
    }
},
```

I get the following output.

[image]

I shall be grateful for a code with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to achieve the desired effect:

```
$Config = Get-Content -path 'C:\Scripts\Reading JSON\InstallationConfig.json' | ConvertFrom-JSon
$ApplicationDevelopment = $Config.WindowsFeatures.IISFeatures
foreach ($appDev in $ApplicationDevelopment.psobject.properties) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $appDev.Name
    $ApplicationDevelopment.($appDev.Name)
    "" # Extra line to separate the groups
}
```

or written another way:

```
$Config = Get-Content -path 'C:\Scripts\Reading JSON\InstallationConfig.json' | ConvertFrom-JSon
$ApplicationDevelopment = $Config.WindowsFeatures.IISFeatures
$ApplicationDevelopment.psobject.properties | % { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $_.Name; $ApplicationDevelopment.($_.Name); "" }
```

[image]

Comment: Just be aware that mixing `Write-Host` and standard output can have unexpected results. There's no guarantee they will display in the correct order. They're totally different streams, and they can flush at different times.

Comment: @BaconBits, I have never seen what you describe.  The code provided here is synchronous and should not suffer from out-of-order streaming onto the host.  If you have a link you can provide that would suggest otherwise or a way to demonstrate this, I would love to see it, but otherwise I'm going to assume it's false.

Comment: @BaconBits, if you are really worried about it or maybe your host behaves differently than any I have used you can use: Write-Host ($ApplicationDevelopment.($appDev.Name) | Out-String)

Comment: There's several SO questions on the output issue that include examples. [Here is one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71708221/696808) that still works on PS v7.3. It's easy enough to create a simplified single-line example: `Write-Host 'Start'; '' | Select-Object @{n='Test';e={'Middle'}}; Write-Host 'End'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`psobject` hidden memberset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.3#object-views) to discover the names of properties under `IISFeatures` :

```
$valuesWithArrayName = $Config.WindowsFeatures.IISFeatures.psobject.Properties |ForEach-Object {
    # extract the property name, eg. "CommonHttpFeatures"
    $name = $_.Name
    $_.Value |ForEach-Object {
        # iterate over all the values and output an object that has both the feature name and the value
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Name = $name
            Value = $_
        }
    }
}

# group the formatted output by section name
$valuesWithArrayName |Format-Table Value -GroupBy Name
```